# Is the interpretation of a "Compatibility Interval" (Greenland, 2019) valid in general?

Tags: confidence-interval, p-value, terminology, frequentist

I was reading [this](https://www.bmj.com/content/bmj/366/bmj.l5381.full.pdf) short paper by Gelman and Greenland, where Greenland proposes to use the term "compatibility interval" instead of "confidence interval" with the following interpretation:

> [...] all values in a conventional 95% interval can be described as
>   highly compatible with data under the background statistical
>   assumptions, in the very narrow sense of having P>0.05 under those
>   assumptions.

In my opinion, this seems to indeed offer a more intuitive and less false-guiding interpretation than the usual "if the experiment is infinitely many times repeated, 95% of the confidence intervals will contain the true value". It is obvious that under normal assumptions the 95% confidence interval of the mean indeed is the range of values for which P>0.05.

However, it is not so obvious to me, whether this holds true in other situations as well. For example, for a binomial proportion I am aware of at least 5 different procedures for the confidence interval. It won't be possible to keep them all in agreement with the proposed interpretation of a compatibility interval, will it? And how is that in more complex situtation, e.g. in mixed models, where we might have confidence intervals for the parameters but p-values may be difficult to define?

Comment: I think this is relevant:   https://statmodeling.stat.columbia.edu/2013/06/24/why-it-doesnt-make-sense-in-general-to-form-confidence-intervals-by-inverting-hypothesis-tests/

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen That is highly relevant indeed, thanks! I will get a very narrow compatibility interval when I have a very bad model - that makes intuitively sense. So, that blog post implies that confidence interval and compatibility intervals are very different terms and just coincide in the case of a nicely normally distributed test statistic? But then I don't really get why Greenland did actually make this proposal? He did not propose to _calculate_, but just to _interpret_ the intervals differently, did he?

Comment: I'm not sure, I guess it would help to look at a lot of examples ...

Comment: Greenland has written more about it, and he stresses that the interpretation only works if the model is "good" (see #19 https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/27209009/). Same for his interpretation of p and s values https://bmcmedresmethodol.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s12874-020-01105-9