# T-tests provide info about the margin of mean difference?

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test, nonparametric

I have 2 unpaired datasets where the difference of the sample means is quite substantial (with the naked eye). The t-test shows that the difference is significant (p-value=0.007) and I would like to know if I can use the t-test to claim that one dataset provides significantly better results than the other or do I have to say that t-tests prove the difference is significant and use confidence intervals (or some other method) to show that one performs better than the other one?

If we go by the description of the T-test on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test): "*The t-test can be used, for example, to determine if the means of two sets of data are significantly different from each other*".
Based on that I believe t-tests can be used only to show if the means are different, we cannot extract info about the margin of the difference or one dataset is better than the other.

Comment: The mean difference of what variable? In the context of your data, what are the results? Is the data paired? please provide some additional info

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Made some changes let me know what else I should change something else. I'm new to this and I don't have a lot of experience

Comment: Over the years social and biological scientists have abused terms  'statistical significance' and interpretations of 'P-values' (some out of confusion and possibly some deliberately). Thus, some applied papers with "false discoveries," have been retracted. Recently, some statisticians including ASA committees, have proposed changes in language and uses of P-values, and  alternate methods trying to clarify how statistical inference should be used. My view is that some of these suggestions have become new sources of confusion and should be regarded as potentially useful works in progress.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> if I can use the t-test to claim that one dataset provides significantly better results than the other

I wanted to point out that the expression "statistically significant" has been discouraged by the [American Statistical Association](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/00031305.2019.1583913). (But personally, I don't feel too strongly against it)

> use confidence intervals (or some other method) to show that one performs better than the other one

Confidence intervals can be interpreted as the range of values compatible with the observed data given the assumptions. In fact, it's been suggested that they should be renamed *compatibility intervals* (see [Is the interpretation of a "Compatibility Interval" (Greenland, 2019) valid in general?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/461453/is-the-interpretation-of-a-compatibility-interval-greenland-2019-valid-in-g) and links therein).

So it seems to me that reporting confidence intervals is appropriate in your case from that little bit I can tell.

I would also note that there is a duality between p-values and confidence intervals since the 95% confidence interval is the range where the p-value becomes greater than 0.05 (or whatever alpha you chose to determine the interval). So the confidence interval is often considered a more informative alternative to the p-value for reporting results.

Comment: Nice even-handed reference to recent proposed changes in how to report statistical results. (+1)

Comment: Since the t-test is a test of the difference between the means, that's the CI that would be reported BTW, just to clarify for the OP. Also, the duality is only true if one is using the Neyman-Pearson approach, setting alpha prior to the test. I wouldn't necessarily say it's more informative about the test, but it is more informative about uncertainty under the test model

Answer (score 6):

Consider the two independent fictitious normal datasets below.

```
set.seed(910)
x1 = rnorm(100, 50, 7)
x2 = rnorm(90, 60, 8)

mean(x1)
[1] 49.86995
mean(x2)
[1] 60.04863
```

The sample means show $\bar X_1 < \bar X_2$ suggesting that $\mu_1$ may be 'significantly' smaller than $\mu_2.$ Welch two-sample t test in R shows that the null hypothesis $H_0: \mu_1 = \mu_2$ is rejected in
favor of $H_a: \mu_1 < \mu_2.$ with P-value near $0.$
More specifically, the one sided CI: shows 95% confidence that
$\mu_1 - \mu_2 \le -8.412.$

```
t.test(x1, x2, alt="less")

        Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  x1 and x2
t = -9.5241, df = 187.95, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: 
 true difference in means is less than 0
95 percent confidence interval:
      -Inf -8.412074
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 49.86995  60.04863
```

Nothing here is a 'proof' that $\mu_1 < \mu_2.$ Of course, because
I simulated these data, we *know* $\mu_1 - \mu_2 = -10.$ However,
in a real statistical application we would not have such exact information.
The best we can do is to
report that sample means show $\bar X_1 =49.87 < \bar X_2 = 60.05$
and to say we are
'reasonably sure' that $\mu_1 - \mu_2 \le -8.412.$

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!
I can accept only one answer and I picked Dario's answer because I wasn't aware of the changes in statistical significance and compatibility intervals.
But your answer is excellent and is equally good.

Comment: And @dariober was first.

Answer (score 1):

If the null hypothesis is $t=0$, then this is testing if the two means are the same or not.  But you can also test $t > a$, then this tests if the margin is larger than some number.